# Is there a point symbol for ArcMap that looks like the Google Maps Marker Symbol?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, symbology, arcgis-10.3

Is there a symbol available through ArcMap (I'm using 10.3.1) that looks somewhat like the Google Maps marker symbol? We have a webmap that was created using Google Maps Engine and apparently we have a need to do this differently now (cough cough). We will be using ArcGIS Server and the ArcGIS javascript API. We thought it would be best if the map changed as little as possible, so I'm looking for one that looks like the old familiar ...
[image: Google maps Marker]
I know that it is possible to create your own symbols using a graphic but the ones I have attempted look pretty horrible. Using some version of the one I just pasted here could potentially work but I wondered if there was one the looks closer than "Circle 3" from the list below (the green circle with a black dot). I could make it red but it doesn't have that "tied to the map" look that the Google Marker symbol has (not to mention it's instant recognition value).

I looked through the symbols available to me and didn't find anything better. Even something remotely close would be fine with me.

ArcMap Symbol Selector:
[image: ArcMap Symbol Selector]

Comment: Just a heads up, the "teardrop-shaped marker icon including a shadow" is trademarked by Google (Or is it Alphabet now?) http://pdfpiw.uspto.gov/50/209/D06/1.pdf

Comment: Thats another good reason not to try to make my own symbol from the existing one. I was hoping for something close in appearance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could take a look at the [maki https://www.mapbox.com/maki/](https://www.mapbox.com/maki/) icon set from mapbox. They've got a couple of teardroped shaped symbols (`marker-stroke` [image: marker-stroke] and `marker` [image: marker]), and are downloadable as SVG and PNG, and if you grab the [github repository](https://github.com/mapbox/maki) there's an ArcGIS Style file. As an added bonus they're released under a [creative commons](https://tldrlegal.com/license/creative-commons-cc0-1.0-universal) license so you can use them where you like.

Comment: Using the style didn't work perfectly because they come in as picture marker symbols (and I couldn't change the color) so I ended up editing the png files and adding the color that way. Great suggestion. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had this issue and after searching through a ton of the pre-set symbols in ArcMap I've found something pretty similar. 
Go into the Symbol Property Editor, select Character Marker Symbol. Then select Wingdings for the Font and on the 5th row is a teardrop shape, if you rotate it 180 it looks like a nice pin marker :)

[image: Symbol Marker]

Comment: I kinda like that one too.

Answer (score 1):

The ArcGIS Explorer marker & 3D sets have pushpins in them that look pretty similar.  They aren't exact but may provide the look you're looking for.  They come in different colors. [image]